# Update row column values automatically

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway for me to construct the **MySQL** table so that `created_date` is set automatically on row insertion and last_edit is updated on row update ?

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldistrict` (
    `distid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `district` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `coid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` DATETIME "ON INSERT... Current datetime,
    `edited_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `last_edit` DATETIME "ON UPDATE... Current datetime ,
    `status` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`distid`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the columns with a `DEFAULT` value and for the update column you can set it for auto update:

```
created_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and

```
last_edit DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The update column will be set any time that at least one column changes values in the row. If an update happens but no columns actually change values then it will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
create_date datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

This only works on more recent versions of MySQL.